# Matlab. Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1)

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to apply FFT onto a set of data. I'm using this script

```
filepath = 'C:\Users\notmyname\Desktop\note.txt';
data = importdata(filepath);
dt=data(2,1)-data(1,1);
Fs=1/dt; 
L=length(data(:,2));
data_fft_full=abs(fft(data(:,2))/L); 
data_fft=data_fft_full(1:L/2+1); 
f=Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;  
figure
plot(f,data_fft)
xlabel('f (Hz)')
```

I receive the error "Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

Error in Untitled2 (line 5)
L=length(data(:,2));

What does this mean? The note file contains a single column of numbers with a space between each number,

Comment: When you use `data(:,2)` , that means `data` is a matrix with at least 2 columns while you say "The note file contains a single column of numbers". Obviously this is an index out of bounds

Comment: So replacing 2 with 1 seems to work. Thanks

Comment: Before fix it, you 'd better know why you or someone write this `data(:,2)` and what does `2` means. To make the error message disappear, I take the liberty of suggesting use `data` instead of `data(:,2)`

Comment: According to your code, i guess the first and second number of data is to calculate `Fs`, and the rest are another type. So use `data(3:end)` to replace `data(2,:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `note.txt` is a file with a *single* column of numbers it will give you the error of indices because you will be calling the second column when you only have one, in that case what you can do is a `reshape()`. I would recommend you to check the `note.txt` file structure because the code is fine. If you cannot solve it, attach it into the post and we can check it.
By the way, the `note.txt` must be something like this:
1 3
4 -5
6 2
...

Cheers,